# Why does a link gets removed from the DOM when clicked instead of just changing textContent?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There are multiple "Read More" links injected to the HTML via JS. Text is truncated, clicking "Read More" reveals it but for some reason instead of changing the link text to "Close", the link disappears from the DOM. Can't understand why.

This appends the link to the article element:

```
s.content[index].appendChild(readMoreLink, s.content[index]);
```

Can someone have a look and tell me what goes wrong when the link is clicked that it gets removed from the DOM?

```js
var ReadMore = (function() {
  var s;

  return {
    settings: function() {
      return {
        content: document.querySelectorAll('.js-read-more'),
        originalContentArr: [],
        truncatedContentArr: [],
        moreLink: 'Read More',
        lessLink: 'Close',
      };
    },

    init: function() {
      s = this.settings();
      this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
      ReadMore.truncateText();
    },

    /**
     * Count Words
     * Helper to handle word count.
     * @param {string} str - Target content string.
     */
    countWords: function(str) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).length;
    },

    /**
     * Ellpise Content
     * @param {string} str - content string.
     * @param {number} wordsNum - Number of words to show before truncation.
     */
    ellipseContent: function(str, wordsNum) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).slice(0, wordsNum).join(' ') + '...';
    },

    /**
     * Truncate Text
     * Truncate and ellipses contented content
     * based on specified word count.
     * Calls createLink() and handleClick() methods.
     *
     */
    truncateText: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < s.content.length; i++) {
        //console.log(s.content)
        var originalContent = s.content[i].innerHTML;
        var numberOfWords = s.content[i].dataset.rmWords;
        var truncateContent = ReadMore.ellipseContent(
          originalContent,
          numberOfWords,
        );
        var originalContentWords = ReadMore.countWords(originalContent);

        s.originalContentArr.push(originalContent);
        s.truncatedContentArr.push(truncateContent);

        if (numberOfWords < originalContentWords) {
          s.content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
          var self = i;
          ReadMore.createLink(self);
        }
      }
      ReadMore.handleClick(s.content);
    },

    /**
     * Create Link
     * Creates and Inserts Read More Link
     * @param {number} index - index reference of looped item
     */
    createLink: function(index) {
      var readMoreLink = document.createElement('a');
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('id', `read-more_${index}`);
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('class', 'btn-more');
      readMoreLink.textContent = `${s.moreLink}`;

      s.content[index].appendChild(readMoreLink, s.content[index]);
    },

    /**
     * Handle Click
     * Toggle Click eve
     */
    handleClick: function(el) {
      var readMoreLink = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');

      for (var j = 0, l = readMoreLink.length; j < l; j++) {
        readMoreLink[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
          var moreLinkID = this.getAttribute('id');
          var index = moreLinkID.split('_')[1];

          el[index].classList.toggle('is-expanded');

          if (this.dataset.clicked !== 'true') {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.originalContentArr[index];
            this.textContent = s.lessLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = true;

            console.log(this.textContent);
          } else {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[index];
            this.textContent = s.moreLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = false;
          }
          console.log(this);
        });
      }
    },

    /**
     * Open All
     * Method to expand all instances on the page.
     */
    openAll: function() {
      el = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');
      for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
        el[i].innerHTML = s.moreLink;
      }
    },
  };
})();

ReadMore.init();
```

```html
<main id="about">
  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>What are "Goals"?</h2>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>Influences</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, nesciunt tempore voluptates, deserunt ab earum magnam asperiores mollitia repellat praesentium optio cum ex cupiditate quasi quas? Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque
      at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the link getting removed? Because you're replacing the entire `innerHTML` (including the button itself) when the "Read more" link is clicked

When you truncate text you replace the entire `innerHTML` of your elements with class "js-read-more" replacing it with truncated text and a read more button.

```
if (numberOfWords < originalContentWords) {
   s.content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
   var self = i;
   ReadMore.createLink(self);
}
```

When that button is clicked you do the opposite

```
 el[index].innerHTML = s.originalContentArr[index];
```

This has the effect of having completely removed the button. So the following line which changes is text to read "Show less" is completely pointless.

To fix this all you need to do is make sure you call `el[index].append(this);` after replacing the `innerHTML` inside of `handleClick`

```js
var ReadMore = (function() {
  var s;

  return {
    settings: function() {
      return {
        content: document.querySelectorAll('.js-read-more'),
        originalContentArr: [],
        truncatedContentArr: [],
        moreLink: 'Read More',
        lessLink: 'Close',
      };
    },

    init: function() {
      s = this.settings();
      this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
      ReadMore.truncateText();
    },

    /**
     * Count Words
     * Helper to handle word count.
     * @param {string} str - Target content string.
     */
    countWords: function(str) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).length;
    },

    /**
     * Ellpise Content
     * @param {string} str - content string.
     * @param {number} wordsNum - Number of words to show before truncation.
     */
    ellipseContent: function(str, wordsNum) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).slice(0, wordsNum).join(' ') + '...';
    },

    /**
     * Truncate Text
     * Truncate and ellipses contented content
     * based on specified word count.
     * Calls createLink() and handleClick() methods.
     *
     */
    truncateText: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < s.content.length; i++) {
        //console.log(s.content)
        var originalContent = s.content[i].innerHTML;
        var numberOfWords = s.content[i].dataset.rmWords;
        var truncateContent = ReadMore.ellipseContent(
          originalContent,
          numberOfWords,
        );
        var originalContentWords = ReadMore.countWords(originalContent);

        s.originalContentArr.push(originalContent);
        s.truncatedContentArr.push(truncateContent);

        if (numberOfWords < originalContentWords) {
          s.content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
          var self = i;
          ReadMore.createLink(self);
        }
      }
      ReadMore.handleClick(s.content);
    },

    /**
     * Create Link
     * Creates and Inserts Read More Link
     * @param {number} index - index reference of looped item
     */
    createLink: function(index) {
      var readMoreLink = document.createElement('a');
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('id', `read-more_${index}`);
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('class', 'btn-more');
      readMoreLink.textContent = `${s.moreLink}`;

      s.content[index].appendChild(readMoreLink, s.content[index]);
    },

    /**
     * Handle Click
     * Toggle Click eve
     */
    handleClick: function(el) {
      var readMoreLink = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');

      for (var j = 0, l = readMoreLink.length; j < l; j++) {
        readMoreLink[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
          var moreLinkID = this.getAttribute('id');
          var index = moreLinkID.split('_')[1];

          el[index].classList.toggle('is-expanded');

          if (this.dataset.clicked !== 'true') {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.originalContentArr[index];
            this.textContent = s.lessLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = true;            
            console.log(this.textContent);
          } else {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[index];
            this.textContent = s.moreLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = false;
          }
          el[index].append(this);
          console.log(this);
        });
      }
    },

    /**
     * Open All
     * Method to expand all instances on the page.
     */
    openAll: function() {
      el = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');
      for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
        el[i].innerHTML = s.moreLink;
      }
    },
  };
})();

ReadMore.init();
```

```html
<main id="about">
  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>What are "Goals"?</h2>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>Influences</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, nesciunt tempore voluptates, deserunt ab earum magnam asperiores mollitia repellat praesentium optio cum ex cupiditate quasi quas? Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque
      at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Of course!  If I wasn't staring at the screen for hours straight, probably would have realized it. Thank you for a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the following is the best way to fix this, but hopefully it illustrates that `el[index].innerHTML = s.originalContentArr[index];` is removing the link from the content.

```js
var ReadMore = (function() {
  var s;

  return {
    settings: function() {
      return {
        content: document.querySelectorAll('.js-read-more'),
        originalContentArr: [],
        truncatedContentArr: [],
        moreLink: 'Read More',
        lessLink: 'Close',
      };
    },

    init: function() {
      s = this.settings();
      this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
      ReadMore.truncateText();
    },

    /**
     * Count Words
     * Helper to handle word count.
     * @param {string} str - Target content string.
     */
    countWords: function(str) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).length;
    },

    /**
     * Ellpise Content
     * @param {string} str - content string.
     * @param {number} wordsNum - Number of words to show before truncation.
     */
    ellipseContent: function(str, wordsNum) {
      return str.split(/\s+/).slice(0, wordsNum).join(' ') + '...';
    },

    /**
     * Truncate Text
     * Truncate and ellipses contented content
     * based on specified word count.
     * Calls createLink() and handleClick() methods.
     *
     */
    truncateText: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < s.content.length; i++) {
        //console.log(s.content)
        var originalContent = s.content[i].innerHTML;
        var numberOfWords = s.content[i].dataset.rmWords;
        var truncateContent = ReadMore.ellipseContent(
          originalContent,
          numberOfWords,
        );
        var originalContentWords = ReadMore.countWords(originalContent);

        s.originalContentArr.push(originalContent);
        s.truncatedContentArr.push(truncateContent);

        if (numberOfWords < originalContentWords) {
          s.content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
          var self = i;
          ReadMore.createLink(self);
        }
      }
      ReadMore.handleClick(s.content);
    },

    /**
     * Create Link
     * Creates and Inserts Read More Link
     * @param {number} index - index reference of looped item
     */
    createLink: function(index) {
      var readMoreLink = document.createElement('a');
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('id', `read-more_${index}`);
      readMoreLink.setAttribute('class', 'btn-more');
      readMoreLink.textContent = `${s.moreLink}`;

      s.content[index].appendChild(readMoreLink, s.content[index]);
    },

    /**
     * Handle Click
     * Toggle Click eve
     */
    handleClick: function(el) {
      var readMoreLink = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');

      for (var j = 0, l = readMoreLink.length; j < l; j++) {
        readMoreLink[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
          var moreLinkID = this.getAttribute('id');
          var index = moreLinkID.split('_')[1];

          el[index].classList.toggle('is-expanded');

          if (this.dataset.clicked !== 'true') {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.originalContentArr[index]; // Does not include created link
            this.textContent = s.lessLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = true;
            
            console.log(this.textContent);
          } else {
            el[index].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[index];
            this.textContent = s.moreLink;
            this.dataset.clicked = false;
          }
          
          el[index].append(this); // Re-appended link here
          console.log(this);
        });
      }
    },

    /**
     * Open All
     * Method to expand all instances on the page.
     */
    openAll: function() {
      el = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-more');
      for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        content[i].innerHTML = s.truncatedContentArr[i];
        el[i].innerHTML = s.moreLink;
      }
    },
  };
})();

ReadMore.init();
```

```html
<main id="about">
  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>What are "Goals"?</h2>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="article js-read-more" data-rm-words="10">
    <h2>Influences</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, nesciunt tempore voluptates, deserunt ab earum magnam asperiores mollitia repellat praesentium optio cum ex cupiditate quasi quas? Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque
      at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
    <p>Autem neque consequuntur sunt accusantium itaque at eum sed consectetur corporis culpa odit ratione, quam commodi provident quae, placeat voluptatum, debitis aspernatur nisi quibusdam?</p>
  </div>
</main>
```